# Disabling/Enabling a button as per a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have been trying to make a form in which as and when a checkbox is checked, the button is enabled. I tried jquery and javascript, but they are not helping.

HTML code of form:

```
<form>
    Name*: <input type="text" size="20" name="name" required /> <br /><br />
    Surname: <input type="text" size="20" /> <br />
    <br /><br />
    Mobile number: <input type="tel" size="15" /> <br /><br />
    E-mail id*: <input type="Email" size="30" name="usr_id" required /> <br /><br />
    Password*: <input type="Password" size="30" id="pw1" required /> <br /><br />
    Confirm Password*: <input type="password" size="30" id="pw2" required /> <br /><br /><br /><br />
    I accept the terms and conditions <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="tc" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Sign up" onclick="form_function()"/>
</form>
```

Javascript-form_function:

```
function form_function(){
        var pw = document.getElementById(pw1).value;
        var conf_pw = document.getElementById(pw2).value;

        if (pw == conf_pw){
            window.location.href('http://www.google.com/sgn_up_conf');
        } else{ 
            if (conf_pw == ""){
                window.alert("Please confirm your password");
            } else {
                if (pw == conf_pw == ""){
                    window.alert("Please enter a password");
                } else {
                    if (pw == "") {
                        window.alert("How can you confirm a password if you have not written anything?");
                    } else {
                        window.alert("Please make sure that you have confirmed the password properly");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Javascript to conditionally disable button:

```
$('#btn').prop("disabled", true);
$('#tc').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#btn').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);}
    }
});
```

form_function() is working fine, but the checkbox-button relation is not working out. Even when the checkbox is not checked, the button is in enabled state, and caries out form_function().

*In this new edit, I have put up the updated form_function(), this time, I have included all possibilities of the two password fields.

Comment: In your form_function() you should also omit the document.getElementById('btn').onclick =

Comment: `$('#tc').click(function() {` would be better as `$('#tc').on('change',function() {` - that way if it changes via a tab/space keyboard action it also fires

Comment: Why have `document.getElementById('btn').onclick =`? Do you need to force them to click twice?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss **document.getElementById('btn').onclick =** is only the redirection of the page to a hypothetical website

Comment: So that line might simply be `window.location.href = "www.google.co.in/sgn_conf";` perhaps? (in an event handler that is...), as I did in my answer as an example.

Comment: If you see my new update, I have replaced all **document.getElementById('btn').onclick = ** by **window.location.href = ** or ** window.alert **

Comment: Thanks to all of you for helping me, especially Nikita and Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you adjust your code to use a simpler set.  I changed your markup to a bit more conventional, not specifically required, I removed all the `<br />` and used CSS to space stuff out.

As to why your code did not work?

1. It has a syntax error.
2. Using the CLICK event, on the first click it gets checked which is OK however if you use the keyboard to check/un-check, it does not fire thus you should use the change event to ensure actions that can change it are accounted for.
3. You have an issue with the href and that odd event hooking, you really want to set it instead. `window.location.href = "www.google.co.in/sgn_conf";`

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#pw1').val() == $('#pw2').val()) {
    window.location.href = "www.google.co.in/sgn_conf";
  } else {
    window.alert("Please make sure that both the password fields have the same text");
  }
}).prop("disabled", true);
$('#tc').on('change', function() {
  $('#btn').prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

```css
form div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <label> Name*:
      <input type="text" size="20" name="name" required />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Surname:
      <input type="text" size="20" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Mobile number:
      <input type="tel" size="15" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>E-mail id*:
      <input type="Email" size="30" name="usr_id" required />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Password*:
      <input type="Password" size="30" id="pw1" required />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Confirm Password*:
      <input type="password" size="30" id="pw2" required />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>I accept the terms and conditions
      <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="tc" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Sign up" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Note: the jQuery code really needs to be wrapped in a document ready handler function to get the property set correctly for a production version, not needed for this one.

Comment: Still, even if the button is clicked, the page redirects whether or not the fields are filled. I tried to change the function from `onclick` in the button tag to `onsubmit` in the form tag.

Comment: You can put both those in there `$('#btn').on('click submit', ` - note you probably want to `return false` on that submit event handler function OR set event propagation to false.  If that is not clear, I can add an example later. i.e. add an id to form and create function to handle `$("#formid").on('submit',function(){return false;});`

Comment: Please show the entire JS as I'm not really good at understanding functions in JS

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    Name*: <input type="text" size="20" name="name" required /> <br /><br />
    Surname: <input type="text" size="20" /> <br />
    <br /><br />
    Mobile number: <input type="tel" size="15" /> <br /><br />
    E-mail id*: <input type="Email" size="30" name="usr_id" required /> <br /><br />
    Password*: <input type="Password" size="30" id="pw1" required /> <br /><br />
    Confirm Password*: <input type="password" size="30" id="pw2" required /> <br /><br /><br /><br />
    I accept the terms and conditions <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="tc" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Sign up" disabled="disabled" onclick="form_function()"/>
</form>
</body>
    <script>
        function form_function(){

        var pw1 = document.getElementById('pw1').value;
        var pw2 = document.getElementById('pw2').value;

        if (pw1 == pw2){
            document.getElementById('btn').onclick = window.location.href("www.google.co.in/sgn_conf");
        } else {
            document.getElementById('btn').onclick = window.alert("Please make sure that both the password fields have the same text");
        }
        }

        $("#tc").change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#btn").prop("disabled", false);
            }
            else {
                $("#btn").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Check the snippet.

Comment: Still there is one problem :  the button is not able to perform the function. When I added the function, only the disabling worked

Comment: Oh, yes there was one. I forgot to call your function onclick, sorry :) I fixed it, please  check the snippet one more time.

Comment: I tried to run the snippet in my browser, in the online one, the whole snippet runs just fine, but when I ran it locally, the button just reset the fields and nothing else happens, should I specify **btn** as a _button_ instead of _submit_? I actually haven't had time to test it till now, the newer snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have a extra `}`?

```
         ...
            $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);}
        }
    ); // < --- remove }
```

Check this working example:

https://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/wqOaaO

I recommend that you use a IDE that has linting or error checking and this sort of issue will be easier to debug!

Answer (score 0):

You had on extra '}'

```
$('#btn').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#tc').on('click',function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#btn').prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I checked all the brackets with sublime text 3, none of the bravkets are extra

Comment: If you see carefully, the singular bracket in front of function() is completed by that extra bracket as referred by you

Comment: Check this line $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);} from your code, and I have removed the last '}' in my code above and is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#btn").prop('disabled', true);//disable
$('#tc').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
           $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);//enable
        else
            $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);//disable
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra ending bracket.

```
$('#btn').prop("disabled", true);
$('#tc').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#btn').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);} // <--
    }
});
```